# How to remove old credit card details from credit card autofill feature in Android One?

Tags: android-one, auto-fill

Every app in my phone (Xiaomi Mi A2, Android One) that implements Credit Card auto-fill still shows my old credit card information even though I have already (a) replaced all my [payment information](https://pay.google.com/gp/w/home/paymentmethods) in my google account a few weeks ago, (b) used 'Scan a new card' feature every time this auto-fill feature pops up and (c) cleared cache and storage of the app that used this feature.

Do you know where these credit card information are kept and where can I reset them?

[image]

Note: The credit card info above were purposefully blurred.

**Other Notes**

Out of curiosity, when I select any of those old credit cards, I get an error popup

```
Request failed: An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later [OR-PMIA-18]
```

This is expected as I have removed them from my google account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reset the Credit Card information by going to Settings > Google > Auto-fill > Auto-fill with Google then switch to different Google account and back again. My guess is this action clears the auto-fill cache.

You might also have some luck clearing the Setting app's cache instead but I have not tried that.

Answer (score -1):

Cleat the App Data which are storing the information.
And if it doesnot work.
your password can be managed by different apps depending on what Brand you are using, SAMSUNG, IPHONE or other every Manufacture has its own official app which manage this kind of information of users.
Like Samsung has Samsung Pass (in settings).

Comment: This is not helpful. OP has mentioned this in the question: "*Do you know where these credit card information are kept and where can I reset them?*"

Comment: bro simply clear the app data ! 
and this could also be in SAMSUNG PASSWORD MANAGER if you are using samsung, or any password Manager in your phone

Comment: You don't get it. OP has no idea what exactly is providing old credential to every app which wants to access credentials. Are you suggesting that OP should clear data for all apps they use? That's too much for something there is no surety to work out good at the end.

Comment: What is OP ? Bro you can simply clear the app data by going into app setting from phone setting, and im telling you that your password can be managed by different apps depending on what Brand you are using, SAMSUNG, IPHONE or other every Manufacture has its own official app which manage this kind of information of users!

Comment: OP means original poster. In this case, the person who asked the question. That said, it is probable that I am not getting what you are trying to convey. As such, I'm leaving the discussion with the assumption that OP or somebody else would be able to make good use of  your answer.

Comment: @MubashirMurtaza problem is I don't know which app is storing that CC information. I don't have Xiaomi's official app installed in my phone too. I suspect it is Google and I have already cleared Google app's storage and cache but it didn't work.